# ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 with 2560x1440 resolution

Tags: display-resolution, radeon, amd-graphics

I have a Sony Vaio VPC-EB3X with this graphics card and it is officially only specified to support 1920x1080 resolution as a maximum. As I got a larger monitor (Dell U2719D) I tried if I can get higher resolution, but the maximum supported on Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 was 2048x1080 only.

I tried to add custom settings with `xrandr`, but none of my multiple different settings worked.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547812/how-to-enable-2560x1440-option-for-display-in-linux-mint) for a different laptop with a Radeon HD 6950. In one of the comments there was a setting with low pixel rate which works for the  5650.

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_RED"  140.500   2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "2560x1440_RED"
```

This setting works fine for me, although the refresh rate is only 34.88 Hz.

Hope that it helps other users with this or other graphic card to use them with higher resolution and extend the live of their PC/laptop.

Then I found the [CRU tool](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) for Windows which had some good explanation about the various constraints and dependencies. From this I understood that HDMI supports up to 165 MHz pixel clock by default. So I tried 165 MHz pixel clock which provides 41.32 Hz refresh rate, and it also works (with 166 MHz it didn't work anymore).

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440@41"  165.000000  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1447 1468  +HSync -VSync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "2560x1440@41"
```

This modline was calculated with the [Universal Modeline Calculator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/umc/) using the `--rbt` option. I had no success with the `cvt` tool, with `--reduced` option it didn't allow me to specify the target refresh rate below 60 Hz.

The [Calculator for video timings](https://www.epanorama.net/faq/vga2rgb/calc.html) was also very useful to calculate a custom modline and understand the setting details.

Finally I added the configuration permanently to my PC by creating a xorg configuration file:

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-0"
    Modeline "2560x1440@41"  165.000000  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1447 1468  +HSync -VSync
    Option "PreferredMode" "2560x1440@41"
EndSection
```

Comment: hi this was really useful and I'm having the same issues. unfortunately i am unable to generate the settings for 2560x1080 :(

Comment: Hi @supersan, with the `umc` tool I get the modline `Modeline "2560x1080x54.75"  165.000000  2560 2608 2640 2720  1080 1083 1087 1108  +HSync -VSync` for 2560x1080 at 54.75 Hz

Comment: thanks so much for the help. I also asked the admin of monitortests.com and he gave me the following settings `Modeline "2560x1080_50" 151.10 2560 2608 2640 2720 1080 1083 1093 1111 +HSync -VSync` (just quoting here for ref if anyone else comes looking)